# Updating a Cell from a Drop Down in the Workbook

Tags: excel, ms-office

The Drop Down is not a Macro.

I created a Drop Down and populated it with dates. When the selected Index is changed, is there as way to use that selected index from the Drop Down to then use it as and index to grab the correct date used for the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the scheme:

[image]

You have to add a column of Index, than you can have two type of Combo. The first (Upper) add a index BEFORE the value that are the index. The second (Lower) add the index, but without showing.
The properties of the two combo are:

```
Upper DropDown.
ListFillRange -> A2:B7
LinkedCell -> C2
BoundColumn -> 1
ColumnCount -> 2
ColumnWidth -> 30 pt;70 pt

Lower DropDown.
ListFillRange -> A10:B15
LinkedCell -> C10
BoundColumn -> 2
ColumnCount -> 2
ColumnWidth -> 100 pt;0 pt
```

After you can use in a cell:

```
=INDEX(B2:B7;C2)      ' Upper DropDown
=INDEX(A10:A15;C10)   ' Lower DropDown
```